# std::basic_string::npos declaration in C++11

Tags: c++, string, c++11

the basic_string class has npos which declared as static const.
Why it declares as static const since C++11, why not simple as:

```
class basic_string{ 
  ................................

 enum: size_type { npos = static_cast<size_type>(-1) };
.........................>
};
```

???

which is good, static const or enum ?

Comment: Why do **you** think the enum is better?

Comment: because, static const variables need definition too, not only declaration.
see,  basic_string source, must be following code:

template< ..... >
const basic_string< ... >::size_type  basic_string<.....>::npos;

Comment: You cannot take address of `npos` if it is `enum`. That  might break some old code where the address is taken; that is probably why it has not defined as `enum`.

Comment: 0.00001% code :)))
May be, but it's very probably situation.

Comment: @Khurshid: I don't find any reason why it should be changed. If there is no reason to change *something*, then it must not be changed.

Comment: static linkage in C++ has more problems! 
example:
struct A{  static const int n = 0 ; };   
const  int m = A::n; // here may dynamic, or static initialization.
const int A::n;

Comment: @Khurshid It is not true that static constant class members have to be defined. You only need to do that if you want to get the address of it (i.e. pass it by reference). I also don't understand your last comment ...

Comment: @Khurshid static const variables may or may not need a definition, depending on how they are used.  (If you never take the address, nor bind it to a reference, you don't need the definition.)  Since it is a template, the definition will not be instantiated unless it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good reason not to do that, the enumeration creates a new type which will at least cause changes when resolving overloads or instantiating templates.

That said, I believe that you can actually declare and define class-static constants in the class definition, or is there some exception to that rule when the class is a template?

Comment: Good point about the template.  I can't think that it's particularly useful, but `std::min( someString.size(), std::string::npos )` would fail to compile if `std::string::npos` were an enum.

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions are pretty much the same. The so called enum hack was born because of compilers which didn't support for in class initialization, mostly. The differences are: you cannot take the address of the enum "variable"; the static const approach is type-safe. Now, in C++11 enum classes are indeed type safe (except you stick to enums).

Basically, then, the only difference is in the "address of" issue. But, when you define an enum class you are defining a type; you might well find it to be bad looking to define a type when what you need is a constant.

Comment: Just a nit, but the enum hack was born because C++ didn't allow specifying the initializers in a declaration.  The standard hack which allowed it was invented precisely because people were dissatisfied with the enum hack (because it resulted in the wrong type).